# binding knockout dropdown in foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a dropdown inside a foreach

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach:  Details">
 <tr style="border: none">
 <select style="width: 130px" 
         data-bind=" optionsCaption: 'Choose...', 
          options: $data.filteredList, optionsText: 'number',
          optionsValue: 'id'">
 </select>
 </tr>
```

This binding does not seem to work. When I debug I can see that the filter is updating but I never get any thing in the dropdown.

I added this:

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

This is the result:

```
{
  "Seed": 1,
  "filteredList": [
    {
      "id": "a",
      "number": "12"
    },
    {
      "id": "b",
      "number": "12"
    } 
}
```

And I can see that the filter values are changing.

Why would the dropdown be empty?

Comment: Can you show this on a Fiddle? I have created one based on some assumptions but it works fine here. http://jsfiddle.net/Pg5Cs/

Comment: Is the object $data also an observable and is filteredList an observableArray() ?  In other words, can you please show your view model and the definition of $data

Comment: @user2643709 You say there is a foreach, can you share the complete outline of your viewmodel and the html bindings. That would help shed some light on your problem

Comment: I updated the code sample.

Comment: Please update your sample as per @CtrlDot request.  That is what stopping us answering your question

Comment: filtered list is a computed

Comment: please show the viewmodel of a typical Details array element, including computed function for filteredList and it's dependencies.  Help us help you

Answer (score 2):

Just change `$data.filteredList` to `$root.filteredList` in the binding if the `filteredList` is a member of `ModelView`.